# Checking condition in elasticsearch _suggest

Tags: elasticsearch

How to check condition in elastic search suggest query

```
GET restaurants/restaurant/_suggest
{
"location": {
    "properties": {
        "name_suggest": {
            "type": "completion",
            "index_analyzer": "whitespace",
            "search_analyzer": "whitespace",
            "payloads": true
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here I have a condition that payloads may be "false" or empty or that payloads may not come. Here how I need to check that scenario with payloads false or payload doesn't exists.

Comment: Question is incomplete please edit

Comment: hi phil .. is it ok now.